# React component - returning a div from inside a .then

Tags: reactjs, promise, return

```
export default function Products() {
  const allProducts = [];

  // Get all products

  fetch('/api/getAllProducts')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then((j) => {
    return JSON.parse(j);
  })
  .then ((pj) => {

    // For each product, create a child element and add it to allProducts array 
    pj.map((pi, index) => {
      // Only pass first 8 products to allProducts array
      if (index < 8){
        allProducts.push(pi.shortdescription);
      }
    })
  })

  // If error
  .catch(error => {
      console.log("ERROR " + error);
  })

  return (
    <div className="products">
      <div className="header">Products</div>
      <div className="strap">See all of the quilts you can buy</div>
      <div className="productsflex">
        {allProducts}
      </div>
  </div>
  ); 
}
```

I'm trying to return the contents of an array as part of a component.

My problem seems to be that I can only populate the array from within a then. Anything I return from a then is a promise so if I try and return the  etc from within the then, it doesn't render anything on screen.

I've tried initiating an array outside of the fetch/then, populating it with the value of the promise and then using it outside the fetch/then and returning the  but the return code as above executes before the promise returns so the array is empty and doesn't render on screen

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

See code snippet and explanation above

Comment: YOu should use a state for that, not an other array.

Comment: You've missed the most crucial and fundamental part of React in whatever tutorial(s) you've been following... *using state*.  `allProducts` should be a state value.  The `fetch` should occur within a `useEffect` and should update that state value.  It looks like you've skipped some React fundamentals that you should return to.

Comment: Also, please don't use `JSON.parse` in a fetch but rather use `j.json()`

Answer (score 0):

First, `allProducts` should be a *state value*:

```
const [allProducts, setAllProducts] = useState([]);
```

Second, the `fetch` operation should happen in an *effect*, not on every render of the component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // put your entire fetch operation here
}, []);
```

Third, in the `.then()` callback you'd update state with your data (without the misuse of `.map()`):

```
.then((pj) => {
  setAllProducts(pj.slice(0, 8));
})
```

As an aside, you'd probably also want to render a structure of some kind rather than just dump the array into the markup.  For example:

```
<div className="productsflex">
  <ul>
    {allProducts.map((p, i) => <li key={i}>{p}</li>)}
  </ul>
</div>
```

The structure you want to use is up to you.  But in general it's best to be explicit about the structure you want instead of assuming a raw array will render as expected.

Comment: Thanks, David. I’m teaching myself and am a complete beginner with React so this is really helpful. It’ll try that and will report back